# in-app billing, how to implement Security.java on a server? (app engine?)

Tags: android, google-play

I've got the in-app billing demo working, but am not sure how to implement the Security.java file on a remote server, as the comments for the class says:

```
/**
 * Security-related methods. For a secure implementation, all of this code
 * should be implemented on a server that communicates with the
 * application on the device. For the sake of simplicity and clarity of this
 * example, this code is included here and is executed on the device. If you
 * must verify the purchases on the phone, you should obfuscate this code to
 * make it harder for an attacker to replace the code with stubs that treat all
 * purchases as verified.
 */
public class Security {
    ...
```

Ideally someone has already put together an app engine implementation (java?) maybe. It's just not clear to me which of these methods needs to go on the server, and which (if any) need to stay on the client.

For example, it's pretty clear that the "verifyPurchase()" method would have to live server side. But lots of the billing requests require a "nonce", and the bookkeeping for them appear to live in both the client code (BillingService.java calls) and from within the Security.verifyPurchase() method, likely server code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some examples on Google code, I think most are using PHP though. There might be something for Java too. In short: pretty much everything has to be on the server if you want to do it right. You need to generate the nonce on the server and save it in the datastore. When you generate a new nonce, you need to check that it's not already used by searching in the datastore (to guarantee the 'nonce' property). When a signature verify requests comes in, you verify the signature, then check if the nonce exists (to guarantee that it's really what you generated).

Recepie: Just take the 'Security` class and make it take inputs from HTTP parametes. What it saves in fields, store in the datastore.

BTW, there is a Google I/O talk about this with some examples for App Engine. I don't think they released the actual code though. Here's the link: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/evading-pirates-and-stopping-vampires-using-license-verification-library-in-app-billing-and-app-engine.html

Comment: Ok thanks. We just want to generate a random number, store it in the datastore, serve it back to the requesting client. Some time later, that client makes a verify request. We just check for the presence of the supplied nonce in the datastore. If present, it's legit. At the end of the verify check, we should delete that nonce from the datastore. But in this setup, someone could try random nonces (probably really small chance) - do we need to tie the nonce to a device signature in the datastore so when we look it up, we can also check if the nonce matches the requestor device signature?

Comment: The purpose of a nonce is to avoid replay attacks: that is, if someone captures a valid, signed response, they could send it again and again, and it will be recognized as valid. When you use a nonce, they can't do this, because the number is only used once. They can't really try random nonces, because the nonce is part of the signed message. Since they don't have the private key, they cannot generate a valid signature, only resend (replay) what they have captured. It doesn't really matter what device it was intended for. So, no, you don't need to store device info along with the nonce.